# Подскажите, как ввести и сохранить переменную с клавиатуры?

Tags: android, float, android-dialog

Сделал диалоговое окно с edit text и 2 кнопками "Ок" и "Отмена", окно работает. Есть переменная типа float, значение которой необходимо ввести и сохранить/пересохранить. 
Вопросы: 1. Как ввести и сохранить значение переменной?
         2. Как обнулить значение переменной с наступлением новых суток/недели?

```
    temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 final Dialog dialogtemp = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                 dialogtemp.setContentView(R.layout.dialogtemp);
                 dialogtemp.setCancelable(false);

             Button btnOk = (Button)dialogtemp.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
             Button btnCancel = (Button) 
             dialogtemp.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);

                 btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View view) {
                         dialogtemp.dismiss();
                     }
                 });
                 btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View view) {
      final EditText = textdialog(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textDialgTemp);
      }

      });dialogtemp.show();
      }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Считываем строку, введённую пользователем
- Пробуем превратить её во `float`
- Если получилось, получаем номер года и номер недели
- Записываем вещественное число, номер года и номер недели в `SharedPreferences`

Примерно так:

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
        final EditText textDialog = (EditText) dialogtemp.findViewById(R.id.textDialgTemp);
        String s = textDialog.getText();  // Получаем введённую строку
        float value;
        try{
            value = Float.parseFloat(s);  // Пробуем превратить её в число
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
   "Неправильный формат ввода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Если не получилось, показываем об этом сообщение и выходим из функции
            return;  
        }
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  // Получаем номер года и недели в году
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int numberOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("data_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  // Открываем файл для записи 
        Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();  // Записываем вещественное число и время
        editor.putFloat("value", value);
        editor.putInt("year", year);
        editor.putInt("week", numberOfWeek);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Чтобы обнулить значение переменной, при входе в приложение можно проверять не началась ли новая неделя. Если наступил следующий год или год остался тем же, а номер недели в году увеличился, то по ключу `"value"` запишем `0`.

Поместите этот код в `onCreate` активности, которая открывается первой (у неё в манифесте должен быть флаг `android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"`):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("data_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int oldYear = sharedPref.getInt("year", 0);
int oldWeek = sharedPref.getInt("week", 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int numberOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
if(year > oldYear || (year == oldYear && numberOfWeek > oldWeek)){
    Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putFloat("value", 0);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Если нужно обнулять переменную с наступлением нового дня, а не новой недели, замените константу `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` на `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`.

Comment: спасибо огромное за подробное разъяснение. Сделал так как вы советовали, но после ввода значения и нажатия "ОК" окно приложения сворачивается.  И ещё один вопрос возник попутно, если позволите: вот этих переменных из моего вопроса 2. Первое значение вводится утром, второе вечером. Собственно вопрос: как сделать, чтобы одно вводилось ДО определённого времени, а второе После? Или просто по очереди.

Comment: @ded-logoped, 1. Что значит сворачивается? Ошибка какая-то? Тогда нужен лог ошибки, чтобы понять, в чём дело. 2. Вот документация класса Calendar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html . Аналогичным образом получайте время и смотрите, что делать. Только я не очень понял, что вы хотите. Если пользователь не захочет утром ничего вводить? Заставить его вряд ли получится, особенно, если приложение не запущено.

Comment: лог вот такой, правда весь не влезет в коммент:01-06 17:32:57.389 23957-23957/e.android.babycare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: e.android.babycare, PID: 23957 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                        at e.android.babycare.MainActivity$7$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:211)

Comment: @ded-logoped, пишут, что textDialog у вас равен null. Видимо, это из-за того, что вы ищете её в активности, а не в диалоге, как, например, кнопки. final EditText textDialog = (EditText) dialogtemp.findViewById(R.id.textDialgTemp);