# Выполнить при включении, если дата сменилась

Tags: android

Добрый вечер.
Запуск Activity должен проверить дату, и если наступило 00:00 следующего дня или любая более поздняя дата - выполнить код.
Могу хранить миллисекунды или строки. Знаю что можно получить дату в определенном формате, но как проверить наступление следующего дня...

Comment: Вот, недавно отвечал на подобный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765179/235436. Сохраняйте в SharedPreferences номер года и номер дня в году, а при запуске приложения проверяйте, не наступили ли новые сутки.

Comment: @КириллМалышев А могу ли я сделать так: храню "date.getTime() / 86400000". Т.е. день. И проверяю так же - если число больше, значит это следующий день.

Comment: ну да, конечно, можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно банально сохранять в SQLite или файл дату последней проверки и потом уже сверять даты. Вы сможете легко проверить что дата последней проверки была допустим 10 января, а сейчас уже 11 января. Если вы пишете на Java или C#, то для этого есть стандартные функции проверки.

Метод сравнения C#:

```
Метод DateTime.CompareTo (DateTime)
```

[Источник](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ata5aya(v=vs.110).aspx)

Пример сравнения C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var date1 = new DateTime(1999, 10, 10);
    var date2 = new DateTime(2000, 10, 10);
    if (date1 > date2)
    {
        //Тут код
    }
}
```

Пример сравнения Java:

```
import java.util.*;

import java.text.*;



public class TestDate {

  public static void main(String args[]){

    TestDate a = new TestDate();

    }



  TestDate() {



    String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 

          new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    c1.set(1999, 12 , 31); 

    c2.set(1999, 0 , 30); 



    System.out.print(sdf.format(c1.getTime()));



    if (c1.before(c2)) {

       System.out.print(" is before ");

       }

    if (c1.after(c2)) {

       System.out.print(" is after ");     

      }  

    if (c1.equals(c2)) {

       System.out.print(" same as ");     

      }  

    System.out.print(sdf.format(c2.getTime()));

    }

  }
```

[Источник](http://javist.ru/sravnit-dve-daty/)